# Looking to modify host file in MacOs

Tags: django, hosts

I am following a [tutorial on multi-tenancy in Django](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wefsc8X5VQ) (10:58/11:42) and I would like to modify the hosts file which I located alreadty. When I try to add a single letter, I get rejected:[image]
But this leaves me quite confused, this is my laptop, and I do not have permission? Is there a way to do this differently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the terminal type `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and then hit return.
Enter your administrator password and then hit return.
Then you should be able to edit the file.